# Why does Android debugger lock up when debugging an app for the first time

Tags: android, debugging, permissions

On newer Android versions, when an app is run for the first time after installing it, Android pops up a screen asking the user whether to grant the permissions requested in the app's manifest. This doesn't seem to work correctly with the Android Studio debugger. The popup screen doesn't appear and the debugger is waiting for the program to start, producing a deadly embrace in which no progress occurs.

A workaround is to click on Force Stop, run the program in the emulator by clicking its icon and give it the permissions that it wants. Subsequent attempts to debug the program from Android Studio will then work normally.

Is there a way of preventing the deadly embrace in the first place?

Comment: No, that's not how permissions work.  THe popup to grant permissions isn't about what's in the manifest, its about what permissions the app is requesting at runtime.  And the app doesn't need to do that right at the start-  in fact its recommended not to do that until it actually needs those permissions.  Doing it at start is the lazy way.  And having done that-  that doesn't cause the debugger any problems, if you're seeing an issue with that its either specific to your app or your setup.

Comment: @GabeSechan, it depends on the android version that the app was built for. If it was built for an older version, some permissions from the manifest seem to get automatically requested at startup because older Androids didn't provide for requesting them at runtime. Up until recently this didn't bother the debugger. I could of course rebuild my app for a later Android version, but that has compatibility issues and also means that my app won't run on older devices.

Comment: You're talking about pre 5.0 devices, which is less than 2% of all devices in the world, and a tiny fraction of those are being used to download new apps.  Worrying about that level of corner case isn't worth your time.  Especially when you're talking about problems only when running a debugger on them.  And when you talk about "compiling for that version", you mean setting a targetSDKVersion so low that it won't be accepted on the play store and will need to be sideloaded.  You're wasting your time on a non-issue with a 3 second workaround.